# NameError: name 'videos_root' is not defined

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, nameerror

I am trying to generate denseflow for ucf101 dataset but I keep getting the following error:

['ApplyEyeMakeup', 'ApplyLipstick', 'Archery', 'BabyCrawling', 'BalanceBeam', 'BandMarching', 'BaseballPitch', 'Basketball', 'BasketballDunk', 'BenchPress', 'Biking', 'Billiards', 'BlowDryHair', 'BlowingCandles', 'BodyWeightSquats', 'Bowling', 'BoxingPunchingBag', 'BoxingSpeedBag', 'BreastStroke', 'BrushingTeeth', 'CleanAndJerk', 'CliffDiving', 'CricketBowling', 'CricketShot', 'CuttingInKitchen', 'Diving', 'Drumming', 'Fencing', 'FieldHockeyPenalty', 'FloorGymnastics', 'FrisbeeCatch', 'FrontCrawl', 'GolfSwing', 'Haircut', 'Hammering', 'HammerThrow', 'HandstandPushups', 'HandstandWalking', 'HeadMassage', 'HighJump', 'HorseRace', 'HorseRiding', 'HulaHoop', 'IceDancing', 'JavelinThrow', 'JugglingBalls', 'JumpingJack', 'JumpRope', 'Kayaking', 'Knitting', 'LongJump', 'Lunges', 'MilitaryParade', 'Mixing', 'MoppingFloor', 'Nunchucks', 'ParallelBars', 'PizzaTossing', 'PlayingCello', 'PlayingDaf', 'PlayingDhol', 'PlayingFlute', 'PlayingGuitar', 'PlayingPiano', 'PlayingSitar', 'PlayingTabla', 'PlayingViolin', 'PoleVault', 'PommelHorse', 'PullUps', 'Punch', 'PushUps', 'Rafting', 'RockClimbingIndoor', 'RopeClimbing', 'Rowing', 'SalsaSpin', 'ShavingBeard', 'Shotput', 'SkateBoarding', 'Skiing', 'Skijet', 'SkyDiving', 'SoccerJuggling', 'SoccerPenalty', 'StillRings', 'SumoWrestling', 'Surfing', 'Swing', 'TableTennisShot', 'TaiChi', 'TennisSwing', 'ThrowDiscus', 'TrampolineJumping', 'Typing', 'UnevenBars', 'VolleyballSpiking', 'WalkingWithDog', 'WallPushups', 'WritingOnBoard', 'YoYo']
find 13320 videos.
get videos list done! 
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "", line 1, in 
    runfile('D:/Clones/py-denseflow-master/denseflow.py', wdir='D:/Clones/py-denseflow-master')

File "C:\Users\sancy\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 704, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

File "C:\Users\sancy\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 108, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

File "D:/Clones/py-denseflow-master/denseflow.py", line 186, in 
    pool.map(dense_flow,zip(video_list,flows_dirs,[step]*len(video_list),[bound]*len(video_list)))

File "C:\Users\sancy\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 290, in map
    return self._map_async(func, iterable, mapstar, chunksize).get()

File "C:\Users\sancy\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 683, in get
    raise self._value

NameError: name 'videos_root' is not defined

How do I resolve this?

`

```
import os,sys
    import numpy as np
    import cv2
    from PIL import Image
    from multiprocessing import Pool
    import argparse
    from IPython import embed #to debug
    import skvideo.io
    import scipy.misc


    def ToImg(raw_flow,bound):
        '''
        this function scale the input pixels to 0-255 with bi-bound

        :param raw_flow: input raw pixel value (not in 0-255)
        :param bound: upper and lower bound (-bound, bound)
        :return: pixel value scale from 0 to 255
        '''
        flow=raw_flow
        flow[flow>bound]=bound
        flow[flow<-bound]=-bound
        flow-=-bound
        flow*=(255/float(2*bound))
        return flow

    def save_flows(flows,image,save_dir,num,bound):
        '''
        To save the optical flow images and raw images
        :param flows: contains flow_x and flow_y
        :param image: raw image
        :param save_dir: save_dir name (always equal to the video id)
        :param num: the save id, which belongs one of the extracted frames
        :param bound: set the bi-bound to flow images
        :return: return 0
        '''
        #rescale to 0~255 with the bound setting
        flow_x=ToImg(flows[...,0],bound)
        flow_y=ToImg(flows[...,1],bound)
        if not os.path.exists(os.path.join(data_root,new_dir,save_dir)):
            os.makedirs(os.path.join(data_root,new_dir,save_dir))

        #save the image
        save_img=os.path.join(data_root,new_dir,save_dir,'img_{:05d}.jpg'.format(num))
        scipy.misc.imsave(save_img,image)

        #save the flows
        save_x=os.path.join(data_root,new_dir,save_dir,'flow_x_{:05d}.jpg'.format(num))
        save_y=os.path.join(data_root,new_dir,save_dir,'flow_y_{:05d}.jpg'.format(num))
        flow_x_img=Image.fromarray(flow_x)
        flow_y_img=Image.fromarray(flow_y)
        scipy.misc.imsave(save_x,flow_x_img)
        scipy.misc.imsave(save_y,flow_y_img)
        return 0

    def dense_flow(augs):
        '''
        To extract dense_flow images
        :param augs:the detailed augments:
            video_name: the video name which is like: 'v_xxxxxxx',if different ,please have a modify.
            save_dir: the destination path's final direction name.
            step: num of frames between each two extracted frames
            bound: bi-bound parameter
        :return: no returns
        '''
        video_name,save_dir,step,bound=augs
        video_path=os.path.join(videos_root,video_name.split('_')[1],video_name)

        # provide two video-read methods: cv2.VideoCapture() and skvideo.io.vread(), both of which need ffmpeg support

        # videocapture=cv2.VideoCapture(video_path)
        # if not videocapture.isOpened():
        #     print 'Could not initialize capturing! ', video_name
        #     exit()
        try:
            videocapture=skvideo.io.vread(video_path)
        except:
            print('read error!'.format(video_name))
            return 0
        print (video_name)
        # if extract nothing, exit!
        if videocapture.sum()==0:
            print ('Could not initialize capturing',video_name)
            exit()
        len_frame=len(videocapture)
        frame_num=0
        image,prev_image,gray,prev_gray=None,None,None,None
        num0=0
        while True:
            #frame=videocapture.read()
            if num0>=len_frame:
                break
            frame=videocapture[num0]
            num0+=1
            if frame_num==0:
                image=np.zeros_like(frame)
                gray=np.zeros_like(frame)
                prev_gray=np.zeros_like(frame)
                prev_image=frame
                prev_gray=cv2.cvtColor(prev_image,cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
                frame_num+=1
                # to pass the out of stepped frames
                step_t=step
                while step_t>1:
                    #frame=videocapture.read()
                    num0+=1
                    step_t-=1
                continue

            image=frame
            gray=cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
            frame_0=prev_gray
            frame_1=gray
            ##default choose the tvl1 algorithm
            dtvl1=cv2.createOptFlow_DualTVL1()
            flowDTVL1=dtvl1.calc(frame_0,frame_1,None)
            save_flows(flowDTVL1,image,save_dir,frame_num,bound) #this is to save flows and img.
            prev_gray=gray
            prev_image=image
            frame_num+=1
            # to pass the out of stepped frames
            step_t=step
            while step_t>1:
                #frame=videocapture.read()
                num0+=1
                step_t-=1


    def get_video_list():
        video_list=[]
        for cls_names in os.listdir(videos_root):
            cls_path=os.path.join(videos_root,cls_names)
            for video_ in os.listdir(cls_path):
                video_list.append(video_)
        video_list.sort()
        return video_list,len(video_list)



    def parse_args():
        parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="densely extract the video frames and optical flows")
        parser.add_argument('--dataset',default='ucf101',type=str,help='set the dataset name, to find the data path')
        parser.add_argument('--data_root',default='D:/Clones/py-denseflow-master/video_classification/data',type=str)
        parser.add_argument('--new_dir',default='flows',type=str)
        parser.add_argument('--num_workers',default=4,type=int,help='num of workers to act multi-process')
        parser.add_argument('--step',default=1,type=int,help='gap frames')
        parser.add_argument('--bound',default=15,type=int,help='set the maximum of optical flow')
        parser.add_argument('--s_',default=0,type=int,help='start id')
        parser.add_argument('--e_',default=13320,type=int,help='end id')
        parser.add_argument('--mode',default='run',type=str,help='set \'run\' if debug done, otherwise, set debug')
        args = parser.parse_args()
        return args

    if __name__ =='__main__':

        # example: if the data path not setted from args,just manually set them as belows.
        #dataset='ucf101'
        #data_root='/S2/MI/zqj/video_classification/data'
        #data_root=os.path.join(data_root,dataset)

        args=parse_args()
        data_root=os.path.join(args.data_root,args.dataset)
        videos_root=os.path.join(data_root,'videos')
        #print(videos_root)
        print (os.listdir(videos_root))

        #specify the augments
        num_workers=args.num_workers
        step=args.step
        bound=args.bound
        s_=args.s_
        e_=args.e_
        new_dir=args.new_dir
        mode=args.mode
        #get video list
        video_list,len_videos=get_video_list()
        video_list=video_list[s_:e_]

        len_videos=min(e_-s_,13320-s_) # if we choose the ucf101
        print ('find {} videos.'.format(len_videos))
        flows_dirs=[video.split('.')[0] for video in video_list]
        print ('get videos list done! ')

        pool=Pool(num_workers)
        if mode=='run':
            pool.map(dense_flow,zip(video_list,flows_dirs,[step]*len(video_list),[bound]*len(video_list)))
        else: #mode=='debug
            dense_flow((video_list[0],flows_dirs[0],step,bound))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable videos_root is not accessible by the `dense_flow` and the `get_videos_list` function, you need to pass it during function call as an argument

Like this

```
video_list,len_videos=get_video_list(videos_root)
```

also make changes to the function definition to reflext this change, as such

```
def get_video_list(videos_root):
```

Comment: I have tried what you suggested but I am still getting the same errors.

Comment: you didn't do it for the dense_flow function, do it for that too

Comment: Thank you for your very helpful comment. So I have done it for the dense_flow function but now I have this error:  File "D:/Clones/py-denseflow-master/denseflow.py", line 186, in <module>
    pool.map(dense_flow(videos_root),zip(video_list,flows_dirs,[step]*len(video_list),[bound]*len(video_list)))

TypeError: dense_flow() missing 1 required positional argument: 'videos_root'

Comment: No, it looks like you dont have much experience with python, so this is what you should do , change this line to  `pool.map(dense_flow,zip(videos_root , video_list,flows_dirs,[step]*len(video_list),[bound]*len(video_list)))` and the first line of code in the dense_flow function to `videos_root,video_name,save_dir,step,bound=augs`

Comment: No, I don't have experience. It's working now, thank you so much!

Comment: Glad to help, could you kindly accept the answer so it is closed :)

Comment: Please I have another question based on the code. I'm using ucf101 as its input but I keep getting a read error message (line 79). I'm thinking its an issue with capturing the data. Do you have any opinion or suggestion on this?

Comment: Its not a Python error. its the try exception for the video_path:  I keep getting the read error from the exception

Comment: `videocapture=cv2.VideoCapture(video_path)
    if not videocapture.isOpened():
        print ('Could not initialize capturing! ', video_name)
        exit()
    try:
        videocapture=skvideo.io.vread(video_path)
    except:
        print('read error!'.format(video_name))
        return 0
    print (video_name)`